# parse an API link message as a server in C (Arduino IDE)

Tags: c++, api, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am using Arduino IDE to program my micro-controller which has a built-in Wi-Fi chip (ESP8266 NodeMCU) , it connects to my internet router and then has a specific IP (as like `192.168.1.5`).

So I want to send commands (and data) by a message which added to the link, then the link becomes as : `192.168.1.5/?A=data1&B=data2`.

When link above is launched from a device within LAN, then I can get the message in a String variable, here I have now a message which contains `"?A=data1&B=data2"`.

So the question is: How I can obtain `A` and `B` contents at separate variables?

Second easier question: How to convert contents to a Boolean, `int` or `float` variables?

Comment: What are you using to host the server? What steps have you taken to even get that link into your program? I feel as though you are putting the cart before the horse here.

Comment: You could use regex capturing groups. Or `strtok()`.

Comment: @Thebluefish , that step i have gotten it ,, you can check this youtube video, it explains how that is reached :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lD2LCJ_jj8E

Comment: @sturcotte06 i am reading about strtok() from here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

i guess that takes string just after token and before next token, which i guess it's hard as a first think .

can you send me to a regex explaining site. please ?

Comment: Why not use [a library for the HTTP server](https://github.com/esp8266/ESPWebServer)?

Comment: @gre_gor can u lead me to one please ?

Comment: @HamzaHajeir I already linked one.

Comment: @gre_gor I haven't find an example for my question there !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm would look like this. This example only print the tokens, but you should be able to modify it to handle the keys, the values and the exception cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE_TOKENS ("=&?")

int main()
{
    char *msg = "?A=data1&B=data2";
    char *msg_dup = strdup(msg);
    char *tok = strtok(msg_dup, MESSAGE_TOKENS);

    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        char delim = msg[tok - msg_dup - 1];

        switch(delim)
        {
            case '?':
            case '&':
                printf("key=%s\n", tok);
                break;
            case '=':
                printf("val=%s\n", tok);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        tok = strtok(NULL, MESSAGE_TOKENS);
    }

    free(msg_dup);
}
```

As for data types, you can use methods of the `ctype.h` header file ([link](https://www.unix.com/man-page/all/3/ctype/)). For example, you can verify if a string is a number by iterating through all characters of the string and verifying that all chars are numbers (the `isnumber()` method).

Comment: it seams a logical answer, i'll try it practically tomorrow .

is there a way to fetch a data by its head? as i could pass A=data1& B=data2 , or pass B=data1&C=data2 ?
so i got now more than 1 case .

i prefer the A,B,C is be replaced as api calls like :app_id,color... 

Thanks @sturcotte06 for your answer , i'll feed it back nearly.

Comment: Thanks @sturcotte06 , it works well .

i'll try that way to parse numbers. but i searched at stackoverflow about converting a hex color code at string (as like : "ffbb26") to corresponding color value, which it's here R=255 (ff) , G=187 (bb) , B=26 ..